# Paypal using Webview

Tags: android, paypal

I want to know if i can integrate the paypal without using paypal library for android. (May be using webview)?

If yes, is there any tutorial to know the process?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: i need you help i need webview URL for paypal integration in flutter app. Please let me know exactly which URL should i use in app ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes; PayPal Mobile Express Checkout. It's basically a mobile view for PayPal Express Checkout. It's dead-easy to implement. Just call SetExpressCheckout, retrieve the token, redirect to https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&token=TOKEN and call DoExpressCheckoutPayment when the user is back on your page.

https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/products/mobile-express-checkout/
https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/mobile/gs_MEC/

Answer (score 0):

if you are going to do this i would suggest note putting it on the android market since they do not like that i would suggest using amazon or any other third party market

What I use this for my donation buttons and have it set as a picture button: note switch the donate to the buy code

`Donate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://www.paypal.com/your_paypal"));
                startActivity(browserIntent);
            }
        });`

to get the link version click the email version when setting up the button.