# native app and paypal integration - "can we pay through paypal.com?"

Tags: android, paypal

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Paypal using Webview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6468674/paypal-using-webview)

So I have implemented android app with paypal MPL integration. App is cool and everything works fine.
I go to my client.

He says ..

"but why it doesnt go to browser? .. I dont trust this paypal popup!
I only make payments if a page redirects me to browser and i can see paypal.com in url..
only then I will type in my data, only then i trust it."

So how I can achieve that?

I was reading about MEPL, but it seems that I would need to implement a webview in my app, am I right?

I know it is possible. Since Facebook is doing something like that if fb app is not present on the phone.

thanks!

---

As mentioned in the comments,

this question answers the same issue

[Paypal using Webview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6468674/paypal-using-webview/6506473#6506473)

Comment: check this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6506473/886001)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments,

this question answers the same issue

[Paypal using Webview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6468674/paypal-using-webview/6506473#6506473)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you are right. MECL is use WEB VIEW. But if you want to pay through MECL then you have to Create a web-service for payment.  and just read the doc of mecl paypal and try to understand flow.

Answer (score 0):

but MECL w/ webviews is not going to help with " I only make payments if a page redirects me to browser and i can see paypal.com in url." since webview doesn't display the url to the user.

So what you need to do is just directly integrate with PayPal Express Checkout (you would need a server side component for this) and launch the browser directly with the express checkout url. Make sure you add code in your returnUrl to re-launch your app after the user is redirected back to your server in the browser.